# What data type is this?

Tags: language-agnostic, data-types, list, constructs

I have a list of items I am adding to, however this special list will delete anything past a given capacity. Note the order is maintained.

For the life of me, I can't think of the name of such a construct.

Consider

```
data = new SpecialListType(3); // set capacity to 3

data.Add("A");
data.Add("B");
data.Add("C");
data.Add("D");

data.Dump(); // returns {"B", "C", "D"}
```

What is this? Some form of a `Set` or `Buffer`? And is there a framework implementation of this in Java and .NET?

Comment: A data structure behaving like this is known as a cache.

Comment: Any data structure can be a "cache" if it's used for caching. @jay: does the structure necessarily preserve the order of the last three elements, or could they come back in any order? If the former, then manilo's answer is correct.

Comment: Clojure `core.async` has a channel with the same semantics that they call a "sliding buffer" which I think is a good name. There is also a "dropping buffer" channel which would have not put "D" into the list and kept "A" in.

Comment: @Ixrec: yes the order is important, I've updated my question to reflect that

Comment: **Regarding the drive-by close votes - please state your reasoning.** I'll be happy to reword

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bounded queue (a first-in-first-out [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29) with a fixed capacity).

This particular queue always allows addition of elements and silently remove head element for newly added element (when full).

In Java there is the [`CircularFifoQueue`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) that works exactly that way (see also [Size-limited queue that holds last N elements in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498865/size-limited-queue-that-holds-last-n-elements-in-java)).

For .NET you'd take a look at:

- [Limit size of Queue in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292/limit-size-of-queuet-in-net)
- [Fixed size queue which automatically dequeues old values upon new enques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852863/fixed-size-queue-which-automatically-dequeues-old-values-upon-new-enques)

Comment: we can have customized queues when required. [see here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62746/64992)